Displaying the GUID partition table in powershell
I am failing to display the GUID partition table in powershell using the get command
I am trying to display the GUID partition table on my PC using the get command in powershell but I keep getting errors. I've tried using Get-GPT

What command have you been using exactly and what error is it giving you?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
